# Best Practice for window functions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have a table with record_id and record_created_time columns (postgresql). I want to calculate duration by minute between timeline of each records. Can I do it with window functions (using `partition by`)?

```
 record_id  |     record_time        | value(minute)
------------|------------------------|--------
 1          | 2019-10-01 01:00:00+02 |  0
 1          | 2019-10-01 01:03:00+02 |  3
 2          | 2019-10-01 02:00:00+02 |  0
 2          | 2019-10-01 02:05:00+02 |  5
 2          | 2019-10-01 02:07:00+02 |  2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with the [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) [`lag()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html):

```
select record_id, record_time, 
       record_time - lag(record_time) over (partition by record_id order by record_time) as diff_to_previous
from the_table
order by record_id, record_time;
```

Note that this will return an [`interval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), if you want the value in minutes, you need to convert that value:

```
extract(epoch from record_time - lag(record_time) over (partition by record_id order by record_time)) / 60 as minutes
```